# Sencha Touch add function to Sencha Component

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, touch

I want to add a function to the Store Class for cleaning the store(proxy+data+sync), which I can call it via `myStoreVariable.cleanAll();` or `Ext.getStore('storeId').cleanAll();`

My first attempt is this, but I can't call this function from the store:

```
Ext.data.Store.cleanAll = function() {
     this.getProxy().clear();
     this.data.clear();
     this.sync();
};
```

My second attempt is this:

```
this.storeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { id: 'myStore', model: 'myModel' });
this.storeStore.cleanAll = function() { /* my cleaning code(see above) */ };
```

It is working, but I don't want to define cleanAll for all of my stores.

Do you know any possibility to add this function to the store class? So I can call it from any store I create via `Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',`

Comment: Are you defining your own store classes? Or you just instantiate Ext.data.Store?

Comment: I am just creating them. `Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { id: 'myId', model: 'myModel' });`. But I want the function for all stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, overriding / adding a method to `Ext.data.Store`

Put this code into your launch config of your `Ext.Application`

```
launch: function() {
    Ext.override(Ext.data.Store, {
        cleanAll: function() {
            this.getProxy().clear();
            this.data.clear();
            this.sync();
        }
    });
}
```